# online quiz , onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

Im preparing an online quiz , and prevent that from unloading by onbeforeunload js object ,
after the time will up , I want to redirect the page to report page , 
but I cant cancel onbeforeunload event !
is anyone knows a trick for it ?

```
var isPostback = false;
window.onbeforeunload = unloading;
function unloading() {
  if (!isPostback) {
    return 'Caution: The timer will not be paused.';
  }
}
```

I want to cancel above event after the time's up

Comment: That code works just fine for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: that fine ! I wnat to cancel this function after time will up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the callback for the timer, you could set `window.onbeforeunload = null` to remove the handler.